# error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
class A
{
    private:
        A () {}

    public:
        static A* getInstance ()
        {
            return new A ();
        }
};

int main ()
{
    A.getInstance ();
    return 0;
}
```

results in the error stated in the title. I do realize that if I create a variable in class A and instanciate it there and return it directly, the error will vanish.

But, here I want to understand what is the meaning of this error and why can't I use it this way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to call the method using the scope resolution operator - `::`:

```
 A::getInstance ();
```

Also, if this is meant to be a singleton, it's a very bad one. Whenever you call `getInstance()`, you'll receive a new object, and you'll run into memory leaks if you forget to delete any instances.

A singleton is usually implemented like so:

```
class A
{
    private:
        A () {}
        static A* instance;
    public:
        static A* getInstance ()
        {
            if ( !instance )
                instance = new A ();
            return instance;
        }
};

//implementation file
A* A::instance = NULL;
```

Comment: yes, yes, of course, this was still test code. am still trying to understand the singleton. thanks.

Comment: You can simplify your singleton implementation by using a static local variable in `getInstance` instead of a static class member.

Comment: don't we have a memory leak here? How it will be destructed?

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov a memory leak refers more to something that leaks continuously, or that can't be freed in the future. You can always clear the memory by calling `delete A::instance` somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Use scope resolution operator `::` (not `.` like in Java for example):

```
A::getInstance();
```

Comment: @AnishaKaul: It is called the scope resolution operator in C++. hmjd: Can you edit the Java bit out -- this may be confusing for newbies.

Comment: @hmjd and now since you have removed that java information, your answer is no different from others. I thought this to be a syntax error, had copied this from a book - didn't know that it was Java's syntax. you shouldn't have removed it.

Comment: @AnishaKaul, this is a C++ question. I only mentioned Java as I often make that mistake when switching.

Comment: If you wouldn't have included the Java information bit, I would have assumed this to be a "generic" syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

`getInstance` is a static function of class `A`. The right form of calling a static function of a class is `<class_name>::<static_function_name>`.

We can also call the static function by creating object of the class and using `.` operator:
`<class_object>.<static_function_name>`

Answer (score 1):

You can call a static member function using either `.` or `::`. However, if you use class name you need to use the latter and an object then use the former.

Answer (score 1):

use scope Resolution Operator **::**

e.g.

```
class::methodName()
```